# What is the parenthesis in a json?

Tags: javascript, java, json

An API call returns a json looking like below:

```
{
    "applicationData": {
        "outerMap": {
            "record(id=1, description=description)": {
                "key(id=1, englishDescription=enDescription)": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "description": "point 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "description": "point 2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "messages": [
        "successfully"
    ],
    "httpStatus": "OK"
}
```

The return type of the API call is:

```
public class Data {
    private Map<Record, Map<Key, List<Point>>> outerMap;
}
```

I don't remember parenthesis is used in json, so quite confused about it. Seesm it could be used to "de-serialize" to restore the object?

Comment: Where and how is this JSON used? These parentheses are part of the key name and have no special meaning without further context.

Comment: Hello, I updated the question a bit and put the return type in Java, the attributes in  Record and Key instances were put in parenthesis but I just didn't know as never seen this before.

Comment: The parenthesis have no meaning here. regarding the JSON syntax. For JSON, they're part of the whole key and are deserialised as such. I suggest looking into custom deserialisation adapters, otherwise your `Map` will contain `key(id=1, englishDescription=enDescription)` verbatim

Answer (score 1):

Every valid string can be a valid key in JSON. So parentheses in key names are possible.

It is up to the application to interpret the content of the parentheses.

Comment: Hi I updated the question. It's the key names in json but in Java, they are actually attribute values, converted and put in the parenthesis.